# update Html.TextBoxFor "readonly" attribute on and off

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, readonly

I'm srugelling with this,
Working on MVC, upon change on Html.TextBoxFor value I want to change a readonly attribute of another Html.TextBoxFor.
I tried several ways-using IE it does not work.
here some code:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.NumberOfQuestion, new { id = "ExamOptions", onchange = "javascript:ReadOnlyHandle();" })

<script>
    function ReadOnlyHandle() {
        //document.getElementById("NoDiffNum").readOnly = true;
        var startHSelect = document.getElementById("NoDiffNum");
        debugger;
        startHSelect.setAttribute("readonly", "true");
    }
    debugger;
</script>
```

and the row in a table I would like to change:

```
<td id="NoDiffNum">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Topics[i].NumberOfNoDifficulltySet)</td>
```

the readonly attribute did not changed - 
any help is most welcome!

Comment: Are you using jQuery, as the tags suggest?

Comment: Have you tried setting the readonly attribute on the input and not on the TD?

Comment: Sorry Sam, I did not understand your suggestion. It looks like the script executes yet the attribute does not change - I tried to play with that - What am I missing?

Comment: `document.getElementById("NoDiffNum")` refers to the `<td>` element not the text box. You are setting readonly on the td.

Comment: Please note that the [tag:model-view-controller] tag is intended for questions about the *pattern*, whereas your question is about the ASP.NET-specific implementation, for which you should use the [tag:asp.net-mvc] tag.

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById("NoDiffNum")` refers to the `<td>` element not the text box. You are setting readonly on the td.

You need to target the text box, not the `td`, so move the id to the text box.

```
<td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Topics[i].NumberOfNoDifficulltySet, new { id="NoDiffNum" })</td>
```

Without jQuery

```
function ReadOnlyHandle() {
    var startHSelect = document.getElementById("NoDiffNum");
    startHSelect.setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
}
```

And with jQuery in your function

```
function ReadOnlyHandle() {
    $("#NoDiffNum").prop("readonly", true);
}
```

If we use jQuery we can drop the inline `onchange`

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.NumberOfQuestion, new { id = "ExamOptions" })
```

And we setup a handler

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ExamOptions").on("change", function(event) {
        ReadOnlyHandle();
    });
});
```

**Edit**

> Based on a value in TextBoxFor element value I want another TextBoxFor element to change its readonly attribute on and off. `<div class="editor-field"> @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.NumberOfQuestion, new { id = "ExamOptions", onchange = "javascript:ReadOnlyHandle();" }) @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.NumberOfQuestion)*@ @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NumberOfQuestion) </div>`

From your comments it's now less clear what you want to set readonly. But in any case you adjust the target id in the change handler.

```
 var targetId = "NumberOfQuestion";
 $("#" + targetId).prop("readonly", true);
```

Comment: I'll try to explain again what I need... since this solution does not work for me...

Comment: Based on a value in TextBoxFor element value I want another TextBoxFor  element to change its readonly attribute on and off. <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.NumberOfQuestion, new { id = "ExamOptions", onchange = "javascript:ReadOnlyHandle();" })
            @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.NumberOfQuestion)*@
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NumberOfQuestion)
        </div>